# to serve for..?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Which of these is the correct usage?

1. The seminar served for relevant discussion.
2. The seminar served for a relevant discussion.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples are grammatical.

Using the following senses of **to serve**:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/serve)

> to have definite use; to answer the purpose; to answer the
>   requirements of

the sentence could simply be:

> The seminar served X discussion.

X = *relevant*, or any other adjectives like *heated*, *convivial* etc....